# How to Create Dictionary Item Only After Multiple Criteria Are Met

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, lookup

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

On `SheetA` I have a unique ID in column H. In Column CK I have some rows with data, some rows without data.

`SheetB` has matching unique ID's to sheet one (not in same order) and the ID's are also in row H.

I need to go through all of column CK on `SheetA` (# of rows varies each month) and for all empty cells found, I need to do the following:

-Find the Unique ID on `SheetB` --> Check Column N for a specific value (ABC) --> add value found in Column AG from this row to a dictionary with the ID (Column H) as key and the item as the value in AG.

`Sheet2` will have multiple rows with the same ID, some will have ABC in COlumn N, others will have a different value.  The non ABC values should NOT be added to the dictionary, and I if two or more ABC lines are found for the same ID, I want to sum the two values found in Column AG.  The end result should be one key (ID) and one item for the key which would be a SUM of all the linss on `SheetB` which have the unique ID in Col. H and ABC in Col. N.

I then need to place the values onto `SheetA` in the blank cells in Column CK without overwriting any lines which already had data in them.

Below is my code thus far:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("SheetA")

Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowForDict4 As Long, LastRowResult4 As Long 
Dim p As Long

 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim wsYTD As 

 Set wsYTD = Worksheets("SheetB")

With ws

    LastRowForDict4 = .Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For p = 1 To LastRowForDict4
If IsEmpty(ws.Range("CK" & p)) = True Then ' And wsYTD.Range("N" & p).Value = "ABC"  'only adds to dictionary if lines has blank value on Column CK but the commented out code does not work because the ID's are not on the same rows on the two different sheets involved



    x = wsYTD.Range("H1:H" & LastRowForDict4).Value
    x2 = wsYTD.Range("AG1:AG" & LastRowForDict4).Value


        'If key exists already ADD new value (SUM them)

If Not dict.Exists(x(p, 1)) Then
    dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = x2(p, 1)
Else
   dict.Item(x(p, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(p, 1))) + CDbl(x2(p, 1))
End If

End If
Next p


End With


 'map the values
 With ws
    LastRowResult = .Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("H2:H" & LastRowResult).Value    'looks up to this range
    ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.Exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))


        End If
    Next i
    .Range("CK2:CK" & LastRowResult).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
End With
```

I know at least part of the issue lies with with this line `If IsEmpty(ws.Range("CK" & p)) = True Then` which I commented about in the code.  I am not sure how to incorporate the second "check" on `SheetB` for matching the ID AND the ABC value.  I would think this needs to be done prior to creating any key / item, but have had no luck with creating another IF  statement.

Best,
Mike

Comment: Is the problem with `wsYTD.Range("N" & p).Value = "ABC"`?

Comment: Is the reference to sheet2 a mistake? Should it be sheetB? And to be a pedant, if there is more than one of the same ID in the column it is not a unique ID but an ID.

Comment: Are the IDs repeated in SheetA? And are these IDs numeric, alphanumeric etc?

Comment: @QHarr   Sheet 2 was a mistake, it should be SheetB as you thought.  ID are a concatenation of Country (letters) and Sales Numbers (Numbers).  There are multiple lines of each ID on both sheets.

Comment: So a problem I forsee is if sheetA has repeated IDs and more than one can be blank you are doing many to many read across. If I came across ID2, for example, for a second time in column H sheetA and it also has a blank column CK for the same row, what number do I put in here? I had thought originally for each unique ID in sheetA, if there was a blank in CK then loop SheetB col H, find each matching instance of the matching ID where ABC in N and sum column AG. But if an sheetA ID can occur more than once with a blank in CK this becomes more problematic.

Comment: Would you repeat the summed figures?

Comment: Also, what datatype is in sheetA column CK?

Comment: @QHarr dataype in SheetA Column CK is all numeric - The summed figures would be repeated on rows on SheetA that were blank and had the same ID.  I may not get a chance to test your code until later tonight, but will update the question when I get a chance to do so.

Comment: @RugsKid My answer will repeat the summed figure across the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I typed it in so apologies if any typos.

Essentially, I create two dictionaries. One for `sheetA`, which holds the `ID` as a key and a concatenated string of the range addresses of the associated blanks as the value. The other dict, for `sheetB`, has the `ID` as key and the totals for each `ID`, where column `CK` is blank in `sheetA`, and `sheetB` has `"ABC"` in column `N`, as values.

I then empty the totals into the blank ranges using one dictionary `ID` to access the other.

Notes:

1) Tbh... functions and subs should really only be doing one thing. The principle of single responsibility so you might look at refactoring this along those lines. An immediate opportunity would be the getting of the last row in each sheet. This could be pulled out into its own function, that returns the last row  when called, with parameters of sheet and column.

2) You might also want some data type validation in there to ensure the values you are processing are of the type expected and there are no data quality issue. I haven't included any error handling.

Happy to add more commentary if needed.

```
Option Explicit

Public wb As Workbook
Public wsA As Worksheet
Public wsB As Worksheet

Public Sub PopulateBlanksCells()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsA = wb.Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set wsB = wb.Worksheets("SheetB")

    Dim shtADict As Dictionary
    Set shtADict = UniqueIDdict

    Dim shtBDict As Dictionary

    Set shtBDict = GetSumSheetBDict(shtADict)

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim rngArray() As String
    Dim item As Long
    Dim total As Long

    For Each key In shtBDict.Keys

        rngArray = Split(shtADict(key), ";")     ', shtBDict(key)

        If UBound(rngArray) = 0 Then
            total = 0
        Else
            total = UBound(rngArray) - 1
        End If

        For item = LBound(rngArray) To total

            wsA.Range(rngArray(item)) = shtBDict(key)

        Next item

    Next key

End Sub

Public Function GetSumSheetBDict(ByVal shtADict As Dictionary) As Dictionary 

    Dim lastRowSheetB As Long

    lastRowSheetB = wsB.Cells(wsB.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sheetBArr() As Variant
    sheetBArr = wsB.Range("H2:AG" & lastRowSheetB).Value

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim j As Long
    Dim shtBDict As Dictionary
    Set shtBDict = New Dictionary

    For Each key In shtADict.Keys

        For j = LBound(sheetBArr, 1) To UBound(sheetBArr, 1)

            If sheetBArr(j, 1) = key And sheetBArr(j, 7) = "ABC" Then


                If Not shtBDict.Exists(key) Then

                    shtBDict.Add key, sheetBArr(j, 26)

                Else

                    shtBDict(key) = shtBDict(key) + sheetBArr(j, 26)

                End If


            End If


        Next j

    Next key

    Set GetSumSheetBDict = shtBDict

End Function

Public Function UniqueIDdict() As Dictionary

    Dim lastRowSheetA As Long

    lastRowSheetA = wsA.Cells(wsA.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim sheetAArr() As Variant
    sheetAArr = wsA.Range("H2:CK" & lastRowSheetA).Value

    'Create first dict with ID and Address of those where ID blank

    Dim shtADict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set shtADict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim currID As Long

    For currID = LBound(sheetAArr) To UBound(sheetAArr)

        Dim colCK As Variant
        Dim ID As Variant
        colCK = sheetAArr(currID, UBound(sheetAArr, 2))
        ID = sheetAArr(currID, 1)

        If IsEmpty(colCK) Then 

            If Not shtADict.Exists(ID) Then

                shtADict.Add ID, "CK" & currID + 1 & ";"

            Else

                 shtADict(ID) = shtADict(ID) & "CK" & currID + 1 & ";"

            End If

        End If

    Next currID

    Set UniqueIDdict = shtADict

End Function
```

Test case I ran:

[image: Test case]

Comment: I just now was able to apply your solution to my file - everything worked great.  Many thanks! @QHarr